# Is there another way to get a property of a foreach loop item?

Tags: c#

I have noticed that a lot of times I need to do something like this

```
foreach (SomeObject item in listOfItems)
{
    string itemName = item.Name;

    ...
}
```

But I would much prefer if there was a way to do something like this:

```
foreach (string item.Name in listOfItems)
{
    ...
}
```

Is this possible in C#?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
foreach (string name in listOfItems.Select(item => item.Name))
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is just what I was looking for :)